# Getting object when is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a module, that fetches some object. Then other modules can use this object. Here is a little example of this task:

```
var Structure = (function(){

    var tree = null,

        df = $.ajax({
            'url'       : '/some/path',
            'type'      : 'POST',
            'data'      : { some : 'data' },
            'dataType'  : 'json'
        }),

        ready = function(cb){
            if (tree) {
                cb(tree);
                return
            }

            $.when(df).then(function(data){
                tree = TreeHandler.create(data);
                cb(tree);
            });
        };


    return {
        df      : df,
        ready   : ready
    };

})();

// Usage:
Structure.ready(function(data){
     console.log (data);
     // some actions with data
});
```

Am I right on doing this? How can this be made better?

Comment: Basically this is completely fine, however I would say it's unnecessarily complex. Can you expand on why you think you need this and can't just use a AJAX call with a callback function?

Comment: For example there are a lot of modules for this application, and all of them are able to use the `structure` obj. If `module1` has already fetched the `obj`, `module8` doesn't have to fetch it again. I imagine a way with `synchronous` AJAX call. After it all modules can simple use fetched object via variable name, but synchronous calls are evil - they block the browser.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/ for some ideas, like:
$.Callbacks('once memory')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm repeating @RoToRa for the sake putting it in answer form for beta-stats:

Your syntax is fine. Without knowing more of the problem domain, it does seem a little unnecessary.  Why not use callbacks on your `$.ajax()` call?